# SQL IN statement take forever to load

Tags: sql, t-sql

Does anyone know why the following SQL statement takes forever to load ???

```
select LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_PRD_RP
from       
    TR_LTM_PHY_CNT  
    inner join AS_ITM_STK   ON (AS_ITM_STK.ID_STR_RT = TR_LTM_PHY_CNT.ID_STR_RT
                            and AS_ITM_STK.ID_ITM = TR_LTM_PHY_CNT.ID_ITM)  
    inner join LE_ACNT_STKG ON (LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_STR_RT = TR_LTM_PHY_CNT.ID_STR_RT  
                            and LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_ITM = TR_LTM_PHY_CNT.ID_ITM)  
    inner JOIN AS_ITM       ON (AS_ITM.ID_ITM = AS_ITM_STK.ID_ITM and AS_ITM.ID_STR_RT = AS_ITM_STK.ID_STR_RT)  
    inner join LO_LCN       ON (LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_LCN = LO_LCN.ID_LCN) 
    INNER JOIN DO_CNT_PHY   on  TR_LTM_PHY_CNT.ID_DCM_PHY_CNT = DO_CNT_PHY.ID_DCM_PHY_CNT  
    INNER JOIN CO_EV        on (DO_CNT_PHY.ID_STR_RT         = CO_EV.ID_STR_RT  
                            and DO_CNT_PHY.ID_EV         = CO_EV.ID_EV)                                     
where   
    LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_PRD_RP >= 4792
    AND LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_PRD_RP <= 6693
    AND LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_PRD_RP IN (
                    SELECT TOP 1 LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_PRD_RP 
                    FROM LE_ACNT_STKG 
                    INNER JOIN CA_PRD_RP ON (LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_PRD_RP = CA_PRD_RP.ID_PRD_RP)
                    WHERE 
                        CA_PRD_RP.TY_PRD_RP = 'CD' AND
                        LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_STR_RT = TR_LTM_PHY_CNT.ID_STR_RT AND
                        LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_ITM = TR_LTM_PHY_CNT.ID_ITM AND
                        (
                          (CA_PRD_RP.TS_PRD_RP_STRT <= CO_EV.TS_EV_ACT_EF AND CA_PRD_RP.TS_PRD_RP_END  >= CO_EV.TS_EV_ACT_EF) 
                           OR --If we're in the latest period, which is still open
                          (CA_PRD_RP.TS_PRD_RP_STRT <= CO_EV.TS_EV_ACT_EF AND CA_PRD_RP.TS_PRD_RP_END  IS NULL) 
                           OR --if there isn't one for the current period, get the previous one
                          (CA_PRD_RP.TS_PRD_RP_END < CO_EV.TS_EV_ACT_EF)
                        )
                    ORDER BY
                        LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_PRD_RP DESC)
```

I believe it's because of the `IN()` subquery. When I take out that statement it loads so much faster. If that's the case, what should I do with it ? I tried replacing `IN` with `EXISTS`, but the result returned is totally different.

Comment: No, it's not forever to load. It's just that your table lacks indexes causing to perform full table scan.

Comment: W.t.... What happened to this query?

Comment: That `SELECT TOP 1` sub-query you have in your `WHERE` clause is not helping either.

Comment: As JW said, i would try and put an index on LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_PRD_RP. Where do these Names come from? Very difficult to read

Comment: Wow, dat readability... How long does the isolated SELECT 1 query take to finish? I think you should see a 1 to 1 correlation between the two.

Comment: I've already created the indexes for the table, no avail :(
and why the SELECT TOP 1 is not helping ?

Comment: This query is not even valid SQL: `WHERE AND ...`. But try running it under `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` first

Comment: OR statements usually perform pretty bad, sometimes it's better to utilize UNION with multiple statements instead.

Comment: So guys, I've tried to create an index for LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_PRD_RP - I still got the same performance ..

An ISOLATED SELECT 1 query return me the result almost immediately .. im now lost :(

Comment: Why are you doing a `SELECT 1` in the first place?

Comment: The query is done by previous programmer .. I believe the reason why he put the SELECT 1 is because he want the sub-query to return the TOP(1) ID_PRD_RP for every single item in the results before the SUBQUERY

Comment: Huh?? My advice would be to step through this. You are using multiple tables and multiple queries, so you should first understand what each is returning, then start putting them together.

Answer (score 0):

Dump the results of your sub-query into a temp table, then join that temp table to your main query.

```
SELECT
    LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_PRD_RP
INTO
    #MyFirstTempTable
FROM
    LE_ACNT_STKG 
INNER JOIN
    CA_PRD_RP
    ON (LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_PRD_RP = CA_PRD_RP.ID_PRD_RP)
WHERE 
    CA_PRD_RP.TY_PRD_RP = 'CD' AND
    LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_STR_RT = TR_LTM_PHY_CNT.ID_STR_RT AND
    LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_ITM = TR_LTM_PHY_CNT.ID_ITM AND
    (
        (CA_PRD_RP.TS_PRD_RP_STRT <= CO_EV.TS_EV_ACT_EF AND CA_PRD_RP.TS_PRD_RP_END  >= CO_EV.TS_EV_ACT_EF) 
        OR --If we're in the latest period, which is still open
        (CA_PRD_RP.TS_PRD_RP_STRT <= CO_EV.TS_EV_ACT_EF AND CA_PRD_RP.TS_PRD_RP_END  IS NULL) 
        OR --if there isn't one for the current period, get the previous one
        (CA_PRD_RP.TS_PRD_RP_END < CO_EV.TS_EV_ACT_EF)
     )
```

Comment: How can I dump the result of the sub-query into a temp table ? If you look at the subquery, it's actually join with the table outside such as CO_EV,  TR_LTM_PHY_CNT etc

Comment: I got the following errors:

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "TR_LTM_PHY_CNT.ID_STR_RT" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "TR_LTM_PHY_CNT.ID_ITM" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "CO_EV.TS_EV_ACT_EF" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "CO_EV.TS_EV_ACT_EF" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "CO_EV.TS_EV_ACT_EF" could not be bound.

Comment: It's a correlated subquery, it cannot be simply dumped into another table.

Comment: hi ypercube, if i cant dump into another table because it's correlated subquery , what should i do then ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply use a group by query like this one:

```
select distinct SUB.ID_PRD_RP from (
  select CA_PRD_RP.ID_PRD_RP,MAX(LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_PRD_RP) AS ID_PRD_RP
  from       
      TR_LTM_PHY_CNT  
      inner join AS_ITM_STK   ON (AS_ITM_STK.ID_STR_RT = TR_LTM_PHY_CNT.ID_STR_RT
                  and AS_ITM_STK.ID_ITM = TR_LTM_PHY_CNT.ID_ITM)  
      inner join LE_ACNT_STKG ON (LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_STR_RT = TR_LTM_PHY_CNT.ID_STR_RT  
                  and LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_ITM = TR_LTM_PHY_CNT.ID_ITM)  
      inner JOIN AS_ITM       ON (AS_ITM.ID_ITM = AS_ITM_STK.ID_ITM and AS_ITM.ID_STR_RT = AS_ITM_STK.ID_STR_RT)  
      inner join LO_LCN       ON (LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_LCN = LO_LCN.ID_LCN) 
      INNER JOIN DO_CNT_PHY   on  TR_LTM_PHY_CNT.ID_DCM_PHY_CNT = DO_CNT_PHY.ID_DCM_PHY_CNT  
      INNER JOIN CO_EV        on (DO_CNT_PHY.ID_STR_RT = CO_EV.ID_STR_RT  
                  and DO_CNT_PHY.ID_EV = CO_EV.ID_EV)                                     
      INNER JOIN CA_PRD_RP ON (LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_PRD_RP = CA_PRD_RP.ID_PRD_RP)
  where   
      LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_PRD_RP >= 4792
      AND LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_PRD_RP <= 6693
      AND CA_PRD_RP.TY_PRD_RP = 'CD'
      AND (
      (CA_PRD_RP.TS_PRD_RP_STRT <= CO_EV.TS_EV_ACT_EF AND CA_PRD_RP.TS_PRD_RP_END  >= CO_EV.TS_EV_ACT_EF) 
        OR --If we're in the latest period, which is still open
      (CA_PRD_RP.TS_PRD_RP_STRT <= CO_EV.TS_EV_ACT_EF AND CA_PRD_RP.TS_PRD_RP_END  IS NULL) 
          OR --if there isn't one for the current period, get the previous one
      (CA_PRD_RP.TS_PRD_RP_END < CO_EV.TS_EV_ACT_EF)
    )
  GROUP BY
    CA_PRD_RP.ID_PRD_RP) SUB
```

Comment: Thanks Remigio .. It says "Incorrecy Syntax near ')' and I couldnt find where went wrong .. Sorry am quite new in MsSQL

Comment: Maybe it's the missing subselect name, I've edited the answer. Anyway I just wanted to show you the general solution, I've not tested the SQL

Answer (score 0):

cipet huat do this,

```
select LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_PRD_RP
from       
    TR_LTM_PHY_CNT  
    inner join AS_ITM_STK   ON (AS_ITM_STK.ID_STR_RT = TR_LTM_PHY_CNT.ID_STR_RT
                            and AS_ITM_STK.ID_ITM = TR_LTM_PHY_CNT.ID_ITM)  
    inner join LE_ACNT_STKG ON (LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_STR_RT = TR_LTM_PHY_CNT.ID_STR_RT  
                            and LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_ITM = TR_LTM_PHY_CNT.ID_ITM)  
    inner JOIN AS_ITM       ON (AS_ITM.ID_ITM = AS_ITM_STK.ID_ITM and AS_ITM.ID_STR_RT = AS_ITM_STK.ID_STR_RT)  
    inner join LO_LCN       ON (LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_LCN = LO_LCN.ID_LCN) 
    INNER JOIN DO_CNT_PHY   on  TR_LTM_PHY_CNT.ID_DCM_PHY_CNT = DO_CNT_PHY.ID_DCM_PHY_CNT  
    INNER JOIN CO_EV        on (DO_CNT_PHY.ID_STR_RT         = CO_EV.ID_STR_RT  
                            and DO_CNT_PHY.ID_EV         = CO_EV.ID_EV)                                     
    inner join 
                    SELECT TOP 1 LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_PRD_RP 
                    FROM LE_ACNT_STKG 
                    INNER JOIN CA_PRD_RP ON (LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_PRD_RP = CA_PRD_RP.ID_PRD_RP)
                    WHERE 
                        CA_PRD_RP.TY_PRD_RP = 'CD' AND
                        LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_STR_RT = TR_LTM_PHY_CNT.ID_STR_RT AND
                        LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_ITM = TR_LTM_PHY_CNT.ID_ITM AND
                        (
                          (CA_PRD_RP.TS_PRD_RP_STRT <= CO_EV.TS_EV_ACT_EF AND CA_PRD_RP.TS_PRD_RP_END  >= CO_EV.TS_EV_ACT_EF) 
                           OR --If we're in the latest period, which is still open
                          (CA_PRD_RP.TS_PRD_RP_STRT <= CO_EV.TS_EV_ACT_EF AND CA_PRD_RP.TS_PRD_RP_END  IS NULL) 
                           OR --if there isn't one for the current period, get the previous one
                          (CA_PRD_RP.TS_PRD_RP_END < CO_EV.TS_EV_ACT_EF)
                        )
                    ORDER BY
                        LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_PRD_RP DESC) temp
   on temp.ID_PRD_RP = LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_PRD_RP
where   
    LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_PRD_RP >= 4792
    AND LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_PRD_RP <= 6693
```

Comment: This is not valid SQL (even with the missing parenthesis)

Answer (score 0):

Good grief this is difficult to test without DDL, the table names are terrible ^^
This might be a step in the right direction, but its so hard to be certain!

```
;WITH CTE0 AS
(
    SELECT   ID_PRD_RP  = TR.ID_STR_RT
            ,TR.ID_ITM
            ,ID_PRD_RP  = MAX(LE.ID_PRD_RP) 
    FROM LE_ACNT_STKG   LE 
    JOIN CA_PRD_RP      CA  ON LE.ID_PRD_RP = CA.ID_PRD_RP
    JOIN TR_LTM_PHY_CNT TR  ON TR.ID_STR_RT = LE.ID_STR_RT AND LE.ID_ITM = TR.ID_ITM
    JOIN DO_CNT_PHY     DO  ON  TR_LTM_PHY_CNT.ID_DCM_PHY_CNT = DO.ID_DCM_PHY_CNT
    JOIN CO_EV          CO  ON (DO.ID_STR_RT = CO.ID_STR_RT and DO.ID_EV = CO.ID_EV)
    WHERE CA_PRD_RP.TY_PRD_RP = 'CD' 
    AND (
            (CA.TS_PRD_RP_STRT <= CO.TS_EV_ACT_EF AND CA.TS_PRD_RP_END  >= CO.TS_EV_ACT_EF) 
            OR --If we're in the latest period, which is still open
            (CA.TS_PRD_RP_STRT <= CO.TS_EV_ACT_EF AND CA.TS_PRD_RP_END  IS NULL) 
            OR --if there isn't one for the current period, get the previous one
            (CA.TS_PRD_RP_END < CO.TS_EV_ACT_EF)
        )
    GROUP BY TR.ID_STR_RT, TR.ID_ITM
)
SELECT LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_PRD_RP
FROM TR_LTM_PHY_CNT  
JOIN AS_ITM_STK     ON (AS_ITM_STK.ID_STR_RT = TR_LTM_PHY_CNT.ID_STR_RT
                            and AS_ITM_STK.ID_ITM = TR_LTM_PHY_CNT.ID_ITM)  
join LE_ACNT_STKG   ON (LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_STR_RT = TR_LTM_PHY_CNT.ID_STR_RT and LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_ITM = TR_LTM_PHY_CNT.ID_ITM)  
JOIN AS_ITM         ON (AS_ITM.ID_ITM = AS_ITM_STK.ID_ITM and AS_ITM.ID_STR_RT = AS_ITM_STK.ID_STR_RT)  
join LO_LCN         ON (LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_LCN = LO_LCN.ID_LCN) 
JOIN DO_CNT_PHY     ON  TR_LTM_PHY_CNT.ID_DCM_PHY_CNT = DO_CNT_PHY.ID_DCM_PHY_CNT  
JOIN CO_EV          ON (DO_CNT_PHY.ID_STR_RT         = CO_EV.ID_STR_RT and DO_CNT_PHY.ID_EV = CO_EV.ID_EV)   
JOIN CTE0   CTE ON CTE.ID_PRD_RP =    LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_PRD_RP                               
WHERE LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_PRD_RP >= 4792
AND LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_PRD_RP <= 6693
```

Comment: Hey Mark, I try to run your statement above but it gave me the following error message: The multi-part identifier "CO_EV.TS_EV_ACT_EF" could not be bound.

Comment: I've modified it, try again. The CTE above is probably also making a lot of the JOINs in the query redundant. I'm also starting to think that this query can be written in a single block using MAX() and GROUP BY, but the tables are killing me!

Comment: Hi MarkD, thanks for that .. I'll give it a try when i get back to office tomorrow .. Do u have any better idea how to get rid of the redundancy ?

Comment: Hi Mark, I tried your script but the results return by the query has 190000++ records, whereas the original one has only 900++ records .. I create a new "Answer" below so that it's more readable .. Do u know what went wrong ?

Comment: Hi, its very difficult for me to comment on why this might be, sorry. My advice; execute the code inside of the CTE to see if the dataset returned is in fact that filter you wish to apply. Once you are certain that it works, check your query below the CTE.

Answer (score -1):

inner join  (
                    SELECT TOP 1 LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_PRD_RP 
                    FROM LE_ACNT_STKG 
                    INNER JOIN CA_PRD_RP ON (LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_PRD_RP = CA_PRD_RP.ID_PRD_RP)
                    WHERE 
                        CA_PRD_RP.TY_PRD_RP = 'CD' AND
                        LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_STR_RT = TR_LTM_PHY_CNT.ID_STR_RT AND
                        LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_ITM = TR_LTM_PHY_CNT.ID_ITM AND
                        (
                          (CA_PRD_RP.TS_PRD_RP_STRT <= CO_EV.TS_EV_ACT_EF AND CA_PRD_RP.TS_PRD_RP_END  >= CO_EV.TS_EV_ACT_EF) 
                           OR --If we're in the latest period, which is still open
                          (CA_PRD_RP.TS_PRD_RP_STRT <= CO_EV.TS_EV_ACT_EF AND CA_PRD_RP.TS_PRD_RP_END  IS NULL) 
                           OR --if there isn't one for the current period, get the previous one
                          (CA_PRD_RP.TS_PRD_RP_END < CO_EV.TS_EV_ACT_EF)
                        )
                    ORDER BY
                        LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_PRD_RP DESC) ) temp
   on temp.ID_PRD_RP = LE_ACNT_STKG.ID_PRD_RP